# How to increase the speed on opening and playing gif?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, image, animation, gif-format

I have a gif `Example.gif`, and would like to play it in a presentation. I used the following code:-

```
a = Import[StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "Example.gif"]]
ListAnimate[a]
```

But it is very slow (waiting time more than 30 seconds up to 1 minute). As I have several gif, the total waiting time is significant. How can I make it faster and smoother to play, just like normal built-in image explorer of the OS? I tried to change the first line from `Import` to the list of images of the gif (that means I have already stored the gif inside the notebook, instead of importing it), but it doesn't help. When I run `ListAnimate[a]`, I still need to wait for the "Formatting Notebook Contents" for a significant duration before the gif is played.

[image]

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully it's more helpful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the purpose is to be able to show animations during a presentation without having to wait for them to load or be generated.

What I would do is to create a master notebook that *produces* the animations, and then a presentation notebook that only *displays* the animations.

- After running the *producer* notebook, click on the `Cell` bracket for an animation.
- Copy the cell to the *display* notebook.
- The copied cell contains the animation embedded as compressed data (unfortunately not very memory efficient, see [How to place an image inside a notebook, with the minimum memory footprint?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/245))
- The *display* notebook can be saved and evaluated as usual, it won't affect the animation output cells you pasted into it (they're not evaluatable).

Answer (score 1):

I get an animation in less than 3 seconds doing

```
Import[path, "Animation"]
```

plus 1 second or 2 for notebook formatting.

Most of the operations give similar timings for a 1.1 MB `"GIF"` file.

```
TableForm[
  {#, First@AbsoluteTiming[Import[path, #]]} & /@ 
  Import[path, "Elements"]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After the comment by @b3m2a1 linking to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176381/10397), it seems this should be considerably faster.

```
ListAnimate@
 Image3DSlices@GIFTools`Private`$ReadAllFrames[path]
```

or maybe read only the frames that are needed as they are needed

```
With[
 {
  n = Query["ImageCount"]@GIFTools`Private`$ReadFileMetadata[path]
  },
 Manipulate[
  GIFTools`Private`$ReadOneFrame[path, j]
  , {j, 1, n, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: All these operations get exponentially worse, though, as the GIF size increases. [The importer is terrible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176381/38205) and extracts the entire GIF stack even to read things like metadata.